# How to enable contextual swashes for Arabic

Tags: xetex, fontspec, arabic, swash

I recently read about Contextual Swashes for Arabic fonts from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenTypeDev/arabic/intro.htm). They have shown an example of how it would look. I've already read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238164/how-to-fix-rendering-of-persian-font-with-xelatex) question and it helped me set up my MWE. Here is a quick visual explanation, I wish to achieve the effect on the right:

[image: Arabic Noon Swash]

Here is my less than MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperheight=2cm, paperwidth=5cm, textheight=1cm, textwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\fontspec[Scale=3.5, Script=Arabic, Contextuals=Swash]{Arabic Typesetting}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Contextuals=Swash]{Arabic Typesetting}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=2.4, Script=Arabic, Contextuals=Swash]{Arabic Typesetting}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
من محمد
\end{document}
```

The reason I used the 'Arabic Typsetting' font is because I saw it use these swashes in a sample file which you can download from [here](http://www.sakkal.com/type/eid_takbir_arabic_typesetting.pdf). If you know any other font which can do it, feel free to replace it (Arabic Typesetting is available on Windows 7 and 8, and I assume 10 as well. It should also come with an Office installation).

So my question is two-fold:

1. Can this actually be done in XeLaTeX? I'm open to manual methods or hacks.
2. Is there a better way to enable this, i.e. using LuaTeX? I have not learned or use LuaTeX.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I’m afraid the answer to your question will have to come from someone who owns the particular font you’re using.  None of the many fonts on my system that support Arabic has the `cswh` feature, and myfonts.com can’t find one either (https://www.myfonts.com/search/ot_exact%3Acswh+charset%3Aarab/fonts/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `cswh` feature in `Arabic Typesetting` font.

However, you can switch on ligatures (`liga`), and justification alternates (`jalt`), and then apply some manual kerning, to almost get something like in the illustration.

[image: kerned]

There is a final form that possibly matches the illustration, but it is under `fina` (final), not `cswh`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{persian}
\newfontfamily\persianfont[Scale=4,
    Script=Arabic,
    ]{Arabic Typesetting}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-liga}
1 من محمد 

\bigskip
\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+liga}
2 من محمد 

\bigskip
\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+jalt}
3 من محمد 

\bigskip


4 من\kern-0.85em محمد 

\bigskip
\bigskip
من  ﺾﺿﺾ

من محمد 
من  ﺾﺿﺾ
%\bigskip
%\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+fina}
%من
\end{document}
```